# I need to send the mail with particular format in PHP what to do?

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor email ....

I am fetching the body content from database,such that my subject is already stored in database,

```
hello
     subject
regards
```

but while i receiving msg i am getting like this, `hellosubjectregards`

any solutions???

Comment: Could You show a header of this eMail?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are sending HTML encoded email.
Since you have no html tags, you might want to send a text encoded email.
Try to set the 'mailtype' preference after loading the email library.

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

If you want nicer emails, build a complete html email (with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags)